# C# - How to handle tasks, which require UAC escalation, in a different program?

Tags: c#, uac

So my problem is that I have an app that every now and then needs to perform a task, which require administrative privileges. I have been reading around a bit and it seems the solutions are to
a) Run a separate instance of the program with administrative priviliges and have it go straight to the task, perform the work and close;
b) Create a separate program which can be run by the "parent" app with administrative privileges, perform work and close

I have decided to go with the 2 separate apps as I think that will be easier for me to implement, however I am somewhat stumped by how I should have the elevated program (hereafter referred to as "the other app") perform the work and how to tell it what work to perform.

As for how, I am thinking I could either move the logic to the other app or send the logic to the other app at runtime ie. via a delegate (seems highly abuseable).
The reason I even mention the second solution is because it feels a bit weird separating the logic, but I am open to suggestions.
As for telling the other app what do to, my only idea is to use arguments when starting the process; here I would definitely appreciate some suggestions on how to do this most effectively

Comment: I'll recommend you take a look at manifest files to give your applications the required priviledges.

http://justlikeamagic.com/2009/05/26/requesting-admin-approval-at-application-start/

Comment: @LeeYiyuan - I think he doesn't want to give his program full admin rights, as it could be insecure. He's looking for ways to safely restrict admin-rights usage.

Comment: @LeeYiyuan As mcmonkey4eva pointed out; my problem is how to handle the coupling of the app and the "escalation service".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`As for telling the other app what do to, my only idea is to use arguments when starting the process; here I would definitely appreciate some suggestions on how to do this most effectively`

That's pretty much the way to do it: Have your second app (A service, perhaps? Whatever it is, with automatic assumed admin rights) launched by the first app, using program arguments.

However, as you seem to be worried about security, you should restrict this carefully: the admin-app should the logic for whatever admin-rights-requiring actions involved, and nothing else. Arguments passed to it should be perhaps as simple as single number identifying which logic set to use [and any side-data that's required] (EG, if argument is '1', use `DeleteLockedFiled()`, if argument is '2 potato', make sure 'potato' is a valid file name then use `SaveSystemFile("potato")`, etc.)

Hopefully this helps you figure it out. If not, please tell me what you're more specifically concerned about and myself or another SO user will try to help with that as well.

Comment: What about sending feedback to the parent app? Exitcodes? Or would it be better to pipe it to the parent app from the escalation service?

Comment: @Jonas An exitcode should be fully sufficient... you have a solid 4 bytes to work with there - you should be able to account for all possibilities within the integer range. If not... temporary output files, or local-network-connections, or many other options...

Comment: The problem I see with using exitcodes is; what if I have to perform more than one task at a time? It seems a bit foolish to launch 100 instances of the escalation services instead of having the service capable of performing multiple tasks in sequence and then close.
The feedback I am referring to is; if something goes wrong which part failed.

Comment: @Jonas - could do bitshifting if you want - (Start with a basic int of `0`, add `1` if firstop passed, add `2` if the second passed, add `4` if the third passed, `8` if the fourth, .. .etc. - then test which worked and which didn't with `if (exitcode & 4 == 4)`) -- otherwise, as I said, running the service listening to the network and having data sent back and forth through a local internet connection could also work.

Comment: I will accept your answer as you made some valid points. As for feedback I have decided to go with exitcodes and then log the specific error to a file.